# image reconstruction using matlab from image coefficients

Tags: matlab, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to execute this function for image reconstruction where
ra, rh, rv, rd are reconstructed coefficients. but i am facing problem in addition and subtraction.

Please help.

```
Xhat = ra2 + rh2 + rv2 + rd2 + rh1 + rv1 + rd1;
sprintf('Reconstruction error (using wrcoef2) = %g', max(max(abs(X-Xhat))))
```

OR

```
XXhat = waverec2(wc,s,wname);
sprintf('Reconstruction error (using waverec2) = %g', max(max(abs(X-XXhat)))
```

I decomposed the image using:

```
   >> a1 = appcoef2(wc,s,wname,1);         
    >> h1 = detcoef2('h',wc,s,1);           
    >> v1 = detcoef2('v',wc,s,1);           
    >> d1 = detcoef2('d',wc,s,1);  

    >> a2 = appcoef2(wc,s,wname,2);
    >> h2 = detcoef2('h',wc,s,2);
    >> v2 = detcoef2('v',wc,s,2);
    >> d2 = detcoef2('d',wc,s,2);
```

Then reconstructed using above parameters. 
Now i have to comnbine them.

Comment: Not enough information.  What are `ra, rh, rv, rd`?

Comment: These are reconstructed coefficients.

Comment: "facing problem" - your code it doesn't do anything, it does something but not what you expected, there is an error (if so, what is the error?).  Have you checked that the `size` of your variables is what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is almost certainly at the `abs(X-Xhat)` line.

Why? You seem to be doing some sort of wavelet decomposition/reconstruction, and if you don't pass in the right parameters your output may be larger than the original image. Therefore it makes no sense to ask for `X-Xhat` if these are of different sizes and you will get an error message.

The best way of fixing this is to when you reconstruct (presumably using `upcoef2`), is to pass size as an additional parameter to truncate. A truncated (heh) and adjusted example from the docs:

```
load woman;
[c,s] = wavedec2(X,2,'db4');
siz = s(size(s,1),:); 
ca1 = appcoef2(c,s,'db4',1); 
a = upcoef2('a',ca1,'db4',1,siz);
a2 = upcoef2('a',ca1,'db4',1);
```

You'll see that `size(X)` and `size(a)` are both 256 x 256, but `size(a2)` is larger. Therefore `a-X`  is fine and `a2-X` will give you a "Matrix dimensions must agree." error.